# Finagle - upgrade ClientBuilder() to New APIs version

Tags: scala, playframework, finagle

I have a project with Scala Play - Finagle and ElasticSearch

I am using a Finagle client with the old version of the API, like this:

```
val client = ClientBuilder()
  .codec(Http)
  .hosts("localhost:10000,localhost:10001,localhost:10003")
  .hostConnectionLimit(1)
  .build()
```

Here is my code:

https://gist.github.com/hectorgool/f217d16e2c15b122d7a7

and works fine, but now i want to upgrade my code to a new APIs version, like this:

```
val client = Http.newService("localhost:10000,localhost:10001")
```

The new version of my code is here:

https://github.com/hectorgool/es-client/blob/master/app/lib/FinagleClient.scala

But, now my project does not compile, I have an error with this line(111):

> 111: val client = clientFactory.apply()()

I don't know how to fix it

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: not enough arguments for method apply: (request: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest)com.twitter.util.Future[org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse] in class Service.
[error] Unspecified value parameter request.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I change this:

```
  val clientFactory: ServiceFactory[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] = ClientBuilder()
    .codec(Http())
    .hosts(hosts)
    .tcpConnectTimeout(1.second)
    .hostConnectionLimit(1)
    .buildFactory()
```

for this:

```
val clientFactory: Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] = Http.newService(hosts)
```

I sumprime this:

```
val client = clientFactory.apply()()
```

And i change this:

```
httpResponse.onSuccess{
  response =>
    Logger.debug("Received response: " + response)
    client.close()
}.onFailure{ err: Throwable =>
    Logger.error(err.toString)      
    client.close()
}
```

for this:

```
httpResponse.onSuccess{
  response =>
    Logger.debug("Received response: " + response)
}.onFailure{ err: Throwable =>
    Logger.error(err.toString)      
}
```

the cause of the problem is:

```
client.close()
```

because closing the connections